# HTML/Text to RestructuredText Converter

Tags: restructuredtext

Any suggestions for an HTML/Text to ReST converter?

Have scoured various options but not finding any solid solutions. (Note: have found Pandoc but would prefer not to have to install Haskell).

Comment: `sudo apt-get install pandoc` is not hard (on Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

[html2rst](https://github.com/averagehuman/python-html2rest) should handle most cases (referenced from the [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) website).

[sphinx](/questions/tagged/sphinx)

Comment: What do you mean by "referenced from the Sphinx website"?